# How can I calculate $\log(e^{e^i})$?

Tags: complex-analysis, multivalued-functions

I'm studying complex analysis and I'm wondering how to calculate the following multivalued function (using the expression $\log(z)=\ln|z| + i\operatorname{Arg(z)}$):

$$\Large \log(e^{e^i})$$

Thank you!

Comment: Obviously it is $e^i$.

Comment: If Leonhard Euler says it, it must be right. @LeonhardEuler

Comment: @strawberry-sunshine hehe yes :p

Comment: $  e^{e^i}= e^{e^i + 2\pi ik} \implies log(e^{e^i}) = e^i + 2 \pi ik$?

Comment: But unfortunately, @LeonhardEuler fixed some "obvious" branch of log and thus oversimplified, as Asem Abdelraouf points out... Either way: The OP should specify what he means by "calculate the multivalued function". Are you looking for all possible values for all branches? Which context does this occur in? What did you try/what are the definitions?

Comment: Thanks for the answeres. @CPCH When I ask for "calculate the log" I mena using the expression log(z)=ln|z| + iArg(z), I guess (I don't understand this topic very well yet). As you said, looking for all possible values, just for one branch (arbitrarily chosen)

Answer (score 1):

The most general logarithm would be $e^i+2n\pi i=\cos 1+(\sin 1+2n\pi)i$ with $n\in\Bbb Z$, as @AsemAbdelraouf noted. The [*principal* natural logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm#Principal_value) is the case $n=0$ (as @LeonhardEuler discussed), with phase $\in(-\pi,\,\pi]$.

Answer (score 0):

The [exponential function $e^w$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_branch#Complex_logarithms), with $w=a+ib$,  is defined as $e^{w}=e^{a}\cos b+ie^{a}\sin b$. So, for $w=i$, $a=b=1$, we have the particular value of the [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula)
$e^{i}=\cos \left( 1 \right) +i\sin \left( 1 \right)$.

Now let $z=e^{e^{i}}$. Since $e^{w\pm i2k\pi}=e^{w}e^{\pm i2k\pi}=e^{w}\times 1=e^{w}$, we then have

\begin{equation*}
z=e^{e^{i}}=e^{\cos \left( 1\pm 2k\pi \right) }e^{i\sin \left( 1\pm 2k\pi \right) }
\end{equation*}

and

$$
\left\vert z\right\vert =\left\vert e^{\cos \left( 1\pm 2k\pi \right)
}\right\vert \left\vert e^{i\sin \left( 1\pm 2k\pi \right) }\right\vert
=\left\vert e^{\cos \left( 1\pm 2k\pi \right) }\right\vert\times 1 =e^{\cos \left(
1\right) }.
$$

The principal argument of $z$, $\operatorname{Arg}(z)$, is such that $-\pi <\operatorname{Arg}(z)\leq \pi $. So $\operatorname{Arg}(z)=\sin \left( 1\right) $ occurs for $k=0$, and, by definition, [the principal value of $\log (z)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_value#Motivation), $\operatorname{Log}(z)$, is equal to

\begin{equation*}
\operatorname{Log}(z)=\log(\left\vert z\right\vert) +i\operatorname{Arg}(z)=e^{\cos \left(
1\right) }+i\sin \left( 1\right) ,
\end{equation*}

where $\log(|z|)$ denotes the natural logarithm of $|z|$.